# Image Processing Algorithm for Detecting Object on a Screen

Tags: image, image-processing, lua

all!

I've been trying to learn how to differentiate objects on an image and I need help. I do not need 'a code', just the guidance on how to solve the problem or introduction to algorithms that do so.

Let's say I've photographed an image of a park using a camera and I would like to differentiate benches on an image. I would approximate them with the rectangle, but I have no knowledge how to do this.

I do not want to use anything like openCV or MATLAB packages or whatever... The reason is I want to code this in LUA language as I would like to familiarise myself with algorithms that can detect objects.

What I thought about doing is creating a black and white image as it seems most logical to me. But, how would you detect and know something on an image is an object? Can you do this avoiding neural networking?

Thanks!

Comment: The task enormous... I would start by looking at which libraries are available and you are prepared to use, e.g. https://luapower.com/libjpeg to make life easier for yourself. You are going to need a library to read/write images, some kind of neural net, and a library to annotate/draw on images. I think you need to get started and come back with more specific questions later because it is too broad at the moment.

Comment: Get a good book on Computer Vision. There is an enormous number of things you can learn about this topic by patiently going through a good textbook. For my undergraduate CV course, as well as my graduate level 3D CV course, I studied a number of algorithms that 1) I was able to use Python to implement (Lua would be just fine! My preference now...) and 2) were algorithms that did not involve neural networks.

Comment: Can you provide some example images with your expected input/output?

Comment: Yes, T A.

So, this is the basic image, for example: https://prnt.sc/ngurzz

I would like to find objects like this: https://prnt.sc/ngusle

Of course, I understand that probably those benches in the background would be hard to spot, but at least I would like that one in the centre of the image to be recognised by the algorithm.

What are the steps to do so? Is it possible to do WITHOUT neural network?

Comment: You could look into Template Matching. I could also imagine that a classifier using HOG or SIFT features in a sliding window approach could yield some decent results. But then again neural networks could probably be less work to implement as there are plenty of libraries.